# For a finite graph $G$ without odd cycles with length at least 5, we have $\chi(G)=\omega(G)$.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a finite graph. Assume that $G$ and its complement $\bar{G}$ do not contain the odd cycles of length at least 5. Please use the fact that "the complement of a perfect graph is perfect and show that $\chi(G)=\omega(G)$. We  recall that $\chi(G)$ is the chromatic number and $\omega(G)$ is the clique number of $G$.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean when you write "It is shown.." Do you mean "Assume that .."?

Comment: And can you also state the Perfect Graph Theorem?

Comment: It is assumed that $G$ and $\bar{G}$ do not contain the odd cycles of length at least 5.

Comment: Are you assuming there are absolutely no odd cycles of length at least $5$, or are you only assuming there are no *induced* odd cycles of length at least $5$?